# Postgres 10 and malformatted array literal when using EXECUTE

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I am trying to create a function on Postgres 10 that would check whether all the given ids exist
in the target table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."has_mismatching_ids"(
  _ids TEXT[],
  _column_name TEXT,
  _table_name TEXT,
  _schema_name TEXT DEFAULT 'public'
)
    RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
$$
DECLARE
  result TEXT[] := '{}';
  _query TEXT := '';
BEGIN
  IF _ids IS NULL THEN
      RETURN false;
  END IF;

  _query := CONCAT('SELECT UNNEST($1) EXCEPT SELECT "', _column_name, '" FROM "', _schema_name ,'"."', _table_name ,'"');
  EXECUTE _query INTO result USING $1;
  RAISE NOTICE 'Executed';

  IF array_length(result, 1) > 0 THEN
      RETURN true;
  END IF;

  RETURN false;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
    STABLE
    SECURITY INVOKER;
```

This is my function that returns correctly true if all the ids exist, but it throws an exception if any of
the ids does not exist.

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."categories" ("category_id" TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO "public"."categories" ("category_id") VALUES ('foo');
INSERT INTO "public"."categories" ("category_id") VALUES ('bar');
```

This works

```
SELECT FROM "public"."has_mismatching_ids"(ARRAY['foo'], 'category_id', 'categories', 'public');
NOTICE:  Executed
 has_mismatching_ids 
---------------------
 f
(1 row)
```

but this fails to even

```
SELECT FROM "public"."has_mismatching_ids"(ARRAY['foo2'], 'category_id', 'categories', 'public');
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "foo2"
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function public.has_mismatching_ids(text[],text,text,text) line 14 at EXECUTE
```

and strangely this works also if I write a function that uses explicit names and without `EXECUTE`

```
SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY['foo', 'foo3']) EXCEPT SELECT "category_id" FROM "public"."categories";
unnest 
--------
 foo3
(1 row)
```

Why doesn't my dynamic function work when comparing to values that do not exist in the target table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a simple SQL to compare if all array element exists.

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION "public"."has_mismatching_ids"( 
  _ids text[],
  _column_name text, 
  _table_name text, 
  _schema_name text DEFAULT 'public' ) 
returns     boolean AS $$
DECLARE res BOOLEAN;
BEGIN 
  IF _ids IS NULL then 
  RETURN false; 
END IF;
EXECUTE format ( 'SELECT  COUNT(*) = cardinality($1)   
      FROM  %I.%I WHERE  %I  = ANY($2)', 
  _schema_name,_table_name,_column_name )
 INTO res using _ids, _ids;
RETURN res;
END;
$$ language plpgsql stable security invoker;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=4c28caca2c00d877740ac7d157b402fa)

Comment: Thank you for your time, I appreciate it greatly! This helps me to reach the solution, but I still do not understand why my original function raises an exception only when trying to match against values that do not exist in the target table. Do you have any idea why is that? This is mainly (and especially) for the academic interest as I am trying to get deeper into Postgres.

Comment: @adrenalin : You're welcome. It's because `result` is defined as a `TEXT []`, but your query (output of `unnest`) results in a **text**. Just try running this and you should get a similar error - `select 'foo3'::TEXT[];`